# AWS EC2 ethernet irq sharing issue

Tags: linux, ethernet, aws, irq

I have create `m4.x2large` instance with `SR-IOV` enabled and running some `sipp` performance testing and i have notice on `top` command `ksoftirq/5` is `100%` and it stick to `CPU5` all other CPUs has 0% load, I want to share irq across all `8` CPUs

```
[root@ip-10-100-2-169 irqbalance]# cat /proc/interrupts | grep eth0
 97:       2119          0          0          0    6581710          0          0          0  xen-pirq-msi-x     eth0-TxRx-0
 98:        576         87          0          0          0    1780987          0          0  xen-pirq-msi-x     eth0-TxRx-1
 99:         34          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  xen-pirq-msi-x     eth0
```

mpstat ( you can see CPU5 )

```
[root@ip-10-100-2-169 irqbalance]# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (ip-10-100-2-169.us-west-2.compute.internal)    03/07/2017  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

10:33:15 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
10:33:15 PM  all    0.11    0.00    0.08    0.01    0.00    2.90    0.17    0.00    0.00   96.74
10:33:15 PM    0    0.07    0.00    0.12    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.12    0.00    0.00   99.68
10:33:15 PM    1    0.18    0.00    0.05    0.04    0.00    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.00   99.58
10:33:15 PM    2    0.08    0.00    0.04    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.18    0.00    0.00   99.69
10:33:15 PM    3    0.05    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.19    0.00    0.00   99.72
10:33:15 PM    4    0.13    0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.18    0.00    0.00   99.63
10:33:15 PM    5    0.17    0.00    0.22    0.00    0.00   23.60    0.17    0.00    0.00   75.84
10:33:15 PM    6    0.09    0.00    0.05    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.16    0.00    0.00   99.70
10:33:15 PM    7    0.08    0.00    0.05    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.17    0.00    0.00   99.70
```

I have tried to disable/enable `irqbalance` daemon to see result but its same. How do i share ethernet irq share on all CPUs ?

Comment: What card/driver are you using for eth0?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to spread IRQ to all available CPU's you need to change the affinity.

For example, to change IRQ affinity for `eth0-TxRx-0`

1. Disable `irqbalance`
2. Verify current affinity

   `# cd /proc/irq/97`

   `# cat smp_affinity`
3. Change affinity by echoing CPU bitmask

   `# echo 0xffff > smp_affinity`
4. Verify `/proc/interrupts` for IRQ 97

You can read more detailed info at [SMP IRQ affinity](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt)